# Azure Front Door + Azure Traffic Manager is posible in azure

Tags: azure

I have two web apps (one is front-end Angular web app and another is Rest Web API for back-end). I would like to use Azure Front Door for global edge location + Azure Traffic manager for routing to my regional location. Since my web app are deployed in app service with multiple region. using Azure front door +Azure Traffic manager i would like to route the traffic based on the geo-location.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to achieve Geolocation routing by traffic manager as well to use Azure front door to protect my application it is possible?